# Redirect one page only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website is like example.com/fr/{slug}.

I have RedirectPermanent in my htaccess to manage page with slug.

But my homepage is example.com/fr/ and I want to redirect it to example.com but only this homepage.

I tried this :

```
RedirectMatch   301 "com\Wfr\W$" "com"
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried this :

```
RedirectMatch   301 "\Wfr\W$" "/"
```

It works but it's a multi language website and when, for example, I'm on the spanish side, url is like this example2.es/es/ and the link to go to french version is like this exmaple2.es/fr/, and I'm still stay on spanish version because of this redirect rule.

Any idea to make the good redirection and make url changing verison work also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} occasion.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} fr/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} barrel.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} en/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} es$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} es/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} it/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
```

Hope this help !!